# mat-checkbox and checked value (A) or checked value (D)

Tags: angular, forms, checkbox

I want to check the checkbox the value you receive is an A and if a D is not checked.

`<mat-checkbox formControlName="active" trueValue="A" falseValue="D">Activa</mat-checkbox>`

trueValue and falseValue do not do anything.

receive the data as form:

```
this.form = this.fb.group({
  active:['' , Validators.required]
});
```

Comment: If you look at the [angular material docs](https://material.angular.io/components/checkbox/api) there is no `trueValue` or `falseValue` attribute. From what i understand of your code `A` stand for `Activate` and `D` is for `Deactivate`. why not have a boolean value: `true` would be equals to  `A` and `false` to `D`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747250/how-in-angular-material-to-set-values-of-y-and-n-for-component-checkbox/56748174#56748174

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use expression in `checked` property:

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="active" [checked]="A ? true : false">Activa</mat-checkbox>
```

The checkbox is checked if A has value if not then it is unchecked. The expression logic depends on your values and need.