# how to pass event and parameter as argument to the function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am try to implement checkbox in Angular(if enabled means event.target.checked value is true and disabled means event.target.checked value is false). By clicking checkbox, I  need to call function
in that I want to pass event and value , I do not know passing event and values as arguments is possible in angular or not ?

Abc.component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="AbcGroup">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-4 text-left" id="email">
                <label><input type="checkbox" formcontrolName="emailData" [checked]="Data.email=='enabled'" (change)="checkEmail($event.target.checked, value)">&nbsp;
                    <b>Email</b></label>
            </div>
        </div>
<form>
<button (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
```

Abc.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.AbcGroup = this.fb.group({
      emailData: new FormControl(''),)}
}

checkEmail(e, value) {
    if (e) {
      value = "enabled"
    }
    else {
      value = 'disabled'
    }
    return value;
  }

submit(){
let emailDataValue = this.checkEmail(event, this.Abcform.value.emailData)
body:{
"email": this.emailDataValue
}
}
```

My doubt is if  'this.Abcform.value.emailData = disabled' means i need to uncheck checkbox and if  'this.Abcform.value.emailData = enabled' means i need to check the checkbox

Comment: It's related to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910767/angular-8-reactive-form-converting-result-of-checkbox-event-to-a-string-value/59919229#59919229)? -the same in this another [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747250/how-in-angular-material-to-set-values-of-y-and-n-for-component-checkbox/56748174#56748174)

Comment: no, it is not related to this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59910767/angular-8-reactive-form-converting-result-of-checkbox-event-to-a-string-value/59919229#59919229) link

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component({
    selector: 'selector-name',
    template: `
        <form [formGroup]="theForm" (submit)="post()">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" formcontrolName="email" >Enabled</label>
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        <form>
    `
})

export class NameComponent implements OnInit {
    theForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
        this.theForm = fb.group({
            email: false
        })
    }
    
    ngOnInit() { }

    post(){
        let formValues = this.theForm.getRawValue();
        let body = {
            email: formValues.email ? 'enabled': 'disabled';
        }

    }
}
```